# svgo removeAttrs how to specify attrs to remove

Tags: javascript, svg, loader

I have removeAttrs set to true, I would like to remove all fill, and color:

```
{
    loader: 'svgo-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: [
        { removeNonInheritableGroupAttrs: true },
        { collapseGroups: true },
        { removeAttrs: true },
      ],
    },
  },
```

But I don´t know how to specify attrs to remove in there...

Comment: removeUselessStrokeAndFill ??

Comment: No remove useless stroke and fill i have tried..

Comment: Please provide full code

Comment: thats cool :) :)

Comment: Could somebody enlighten me as on how to use this on the command line? I want to get rid of a lot of 'forbidden' data-name attributes in a bunch of SVG files.
 “svgo . enable=removeAttrs data-name” doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```js
{
  loader: 'svgo-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: [
      { removeNonInheritableGroupAttrs: true },
      { collapseGroups: true },
      { removeAttrs: { attrs: '(fill|stroke)' } },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Now i would like to use this code to be able to define my style for different svgs. Simply said i want to eliminate fill and stroke from svgs  containing in name Multicolor. Name like:                                                            
   callIcon.Multicolor.svg.

Comment: did you find a solution to keep multicolor specific icons?